# reading data in to make a class object isnt working java

Tags: java

ok, so the data file is simple looks like this: 1 user pass name bday
the 1 is the amount of rows which is only one right now. Well with this code when I am trying to print out the log of the user it prints this login@33acf5f7

how do I fix this to print that it is log[0] and how do I make this code so I can end up printing things like log[0].getName or do I have that part right itll end up working?

```
public class Project {

    public Scanner sc;
    login[] log;

    public int readData() {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File("src/input.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        int rows = sc.nextInt();
        int data = 4;
        // Fill in data
        log = new login[rows];
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; i < data; j++) {

                    String user = sc.next();
                    String password = sc.next();
                    String name = sc.next();
                    String bday = sc.next();
                    log[j] = new login(rows, user, password, name, bday);
                    System.out.println(log[i].getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR HERE");
        }

        return 0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Project proj = new Project();
        proj.readData();

    }

}

class login {

    private char[] user, pass, name, bday;
    private String getName;

    public login(int i, String user, String pass, String name, String bday) {
        this.user = user.toCharArray();
        this.pass = pass.toCharArray();
        this.name = name.toCharArray();
        this.bday = bday.toCharArray();
    }

    public char[] getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is inside of your `src/input.txt` show us at least part of it!

Comment: Also take a look at this thread on how to read a file with scanner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185727/reading-a-txt-file-using-scanner if it wont help add a comment

Comment: the reading in works... I am trying to ok, so the data file is simple looks like this: 1 user pass name bday the 1 is the amount of rows which is only one right now. Well with this code when I am trying to print out the log of the user it prints this login@33acf5f7

how do I fix this to print that it is log[0] and how do I make this code so I can end up printing things like log[0].getName or do I have that part right itll end up working?  The input file looks like this:  1 user pass name bday

Answer (score 0):

Your `login` class is very strange. Why are you using `char[]` instead of `String`? That is very C-like. The reason that your `System.out.println()` is causing weird output is because it's printing the memory location of the array rather than the String that you are attempting to represent.

Use `String` instead.

```
class login {

    private String user, pass, name, bday;

    public login(int i, String user, String pass, String name, String bday) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.name = name;
        this.bday = bday;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Also, regarding your line:

`private String getName;`

I am not sure if you were attempting to forward-declare your method like in C, but you don't need to do so in Java, so I removed the line.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

First read about the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) You have the `login` class which should be named `Login`

In the Login class you have a String attribute called `getName` that is no need of it if you already have a String attribute named `name` also `getName` is conventionally used for a getter method (which you are already using).

Still on your `login` class you created a constructor that is:

```
public login(int i, String user, String pass, String name, String bday)
```

No need for that `int i` attribute since there is nothing to use it on your class. If you plan to add something about it later, ok.

Your Login class should be:

```
public class Login {
    private String user, pass, name, bday;

    public Login(String user, String pass, String name, String bday) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.name = name;
        this.bday = bday;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Now for the reading part of your code. If you plan to have the number of lines on your file to use it as a start you will have to change your code a bit to it get everything you need. So your file looks like:

```
1 user pass name bday
```

Then to read it you use the following code, changing jut the `try catch` block:

```
try {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            String user = sc.next();
            String password = sc.next();
            String name = sc.next();
            String bday = sc.next();
            log[i] = new Login(rows, user, password, name, bday);
            System.out.println(log[i].getName());
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've change the first for `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {` to `while (sc.hasNextLine()) {` To the `Scanner` would go through every line of your file. They way you are reading the data from your file `sc.next();` Already gets the data before the spaces so you had a problem with it when you where trying to read from the file within this for `for (int j = 0; i < data; j++)` If you already know that in your file you have the first line with the number of lines and each data separeted with a space there is no need to that `for`

So the `readData` method code for your Project class should be:

```
public void readData() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("src/input.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //As you are starting always use this command on an exception block
        //it will print what happened with your code, it will be easier to
        //help you if we know what happened.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int rows = sc.nextInt();
    int data = 4;
    // Fill in data
    log = new Login[rows];
    /*
    * Since you know that your file has the number of lines first
    * you must read this value before the while so The Scanner class
    * would get it and go on in the same line.
    * If you want to add another line add it whitout the number of lines
    * like this:
    * >2 user pass name bday
    * >user2 pass2 name2 bday2
    * Otherwise you will need to change your code a bit.
    */
    try {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                String user = sc.next();
                String password = sc.next();
                String name = sc.next();
                String bday = sc.next();
                log[i] = new Login(rows, user, password, name, bday);
                System.out.println(log[i].getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.