# Retrieving specific strings from a file

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList<String>` that contains 3 words ("one", "two" and "three"). There is a file of strings. I need to find strings in the file that contain exactly two items in the `ArrayList`. How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks for sharing that with us. If you have a specific problem during your implementation, then include that information and we'll help you solve it. Good luck with your program!

Comment: You can use java Scanner for reading the file and for each string you can run a loop and check your condition.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185727/reading-a-txt-file-using-scanner-class-in-java]

Comment: The code looks like this:

Comment: Due to conditions I have to read lines this way: BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

Comment: And then by using filereader.readline()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you have to read the string/content which should be analyzed. Then you can count keywords from your ArrayList in the content. For each keyword you test if it's in the content, in this case the count is increased. If the count is 2 you found your string.

```
public ArrayList<String> findStrings(ArrayList<String> searchStrings) {
    ArrayList<String> foundStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    while (hasMoreLines()) {
        String content = getNextString();
        if (countStrings(content, searchStrings) == 2) {
            foundStrings.add(content);
        }
    }
    return foundStrings;
}

private int countStrings(String content, ArrayList<String> searchStrings) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String searchString : searchStrings) {
        if (content.contains(searchString)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

`hasMoreLines` and `getNextString` are missing and must be implemented, perferable with `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Thanks Roland. Your advice helped me.