# Trying to create hashmap and print out it's contents (keys)

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a text file that I'm reading from and I'm trying to use the words in the text as file as keys in a hashmap.  I then want to print the hashmap to see it's contents.  This is a prelude to a larger project.  I know I could simply print out the text file, but I'm trying to experiment with the hashmap data structure.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;  //needed for File class below
import java.util.*;  //needed for Scanner class below

public class readIn {

    public static void readInWords(String fileName){
        try{
            //open up the file
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            HashMap hm = new HashMap();
            while(input.hasNext()){
                //read in 1 word at a time and increment our count
                String x = input.next();
                System.out.println(x);
                hm.put(x);
            }
            System.out.println(hm);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Something went really wrong...");
        }   
    }


        public static void main(String args[]){
        int x = 10;  //can read in from user or simply set here

        String fileName = "test.txt";
        readInWords(fileName);
    }
}
```

When I run, I get a "no suitable method found for put(string)" error.  My larger goal is to create this hash map and store a list of places where a certain keys appears as a value.  However right now I'm just trying to learn more about hashmaps through practice and wanted to see if anyone knows why this doesn't work.

Comment: What problems are you having with this code??

Comment: And what's your specific question?

Comment: Are you sure test.txt is exist or in right place?

Comment: First, you need to read the file line by line, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185727/reading-a-txt-file-using-scanner-class-in-java, Second, split each line by space, so that you get words, Third, HashMap expects a key and value, in your case, if you don't want to put any value, either put a dummy object (new Object()) or use HashSet.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely in the right place.  it's in the same directory.  When I put a line in my while loop like System.println(x) (refering to the string I defined).  The code compiles and runs perfectly.

Comment: What do you think "no suitable method found for put(string)" means?

Comment: You should look at the Java reference, so you know what functions you can use. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: RP:  Is there a split function similar to the python split function?

Comment: Tunaki: I'm guessing it means I can't use a string in my hashmap.  However I'm seen numerous examples online where people have succesfully done it.

Comment: Why do you think that? The error tells you that there is no suitable _method_. So the method `put(String)` doesn't exist. And if you look [at the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), indeed, it doesn't exist. Because it is `put(key, value)`.

Comment: Tunaki: Sorry I literally just started learning java yesterday and I'm relatively new to coding in general. So there's no suitable method for storing a string as a key in a hashmap?

Comment: The code compiles perfectly? With your put method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no **.put(x)** method in **Map** iterface. You must use put() method with key argument. In your situation do it like this: `hm.put(x, x);`

Comment: I got an error that says readIn.java users unchecked or unsafe operations.  and that I should recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.  What exactly does this mean?  What was unsafe?

Comment: HashMap type is unsafe. Change to HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

Comment: this works, thanks!  Is there an easy to initialize the value of my hashmap as an array?

Comment: Nope, there are no such way. You need to init like above. If it is not compatible to your problem. Then you can use Vector, List or ...