# how to import arraylist from inotepad file

Tags: java, macos, arraylist, iterator, java.util.scanner

I am currently working on a project and I have already created an arraylist within my program.  However, I am now trying to import the list from an external inotepad file so I can simply change the contents of the file instead adding new lines into the program itself.  I've attempted to use a scanner to pull the list but it doesn't seem as if I am doing it correctly.  The examples I am finding online show using a scanner, but I don't know how I can translate it into an existing array.  I could definitely use some guidance!

Program:

```
package animalNames;

import java.util.*;
public class animalList {

public static void main(String args[]) {
// Create a new array list
ArrayList animalNames = new ArrayList();

// add animals to the array list
animalNames.add("Aligator");
animalNames.add("Rabbit");
animalNames.add("Snake");
animalNames.add("Spider");
animalNames.add("Turtle");
animalNames.add("Dog");

// Allow iterator to show contents of array list
System.out.print("Animals kept at the zoo: ");
Iterator itr = animalNames.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Object element = itr.next();
    System.out.print(element + " ");
}
System.out.println();

// Change the contents within array list
ListIterator litr = animalNames.listIterator();

while(litr.hasNext()) {
    Object element = litr.next();
    litr.set("1 " + element + " ");
}
System.out.print("There is exactly: ");
itr = animalNames.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Object element = itr.next();
    System.out.print(element);
}
System.out.println();

// Display array list backwards
System.out.print("Display list backward: ");

while(litr.hasPrevious()) {
    Object element = litr.previous();
    System.out.print(element + " ");
}
System.out.println();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The point is: when reading data from a file, there is no "existing" array.

In other words:

- your use case is: you *hard code* a List (which is **not** the same as an **array**), and then iterate over that content
- when using data from a file, you read the file, and put that content into a previously **empty** list

You can find extensive explanations how to do that using a Scanner [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185727/reading-a-txt-file-using-scanner-class-in-java) for example.

Please understand: there are no detours. You have to step back and **study** such tutorials until you understand what they do. We can't explain such things in one sentence to you. It simply takes the time that it takes ...

Answer (score 0):

To read from a file and populate a List, this will work.

`List<String> lines = 
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file_path"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`