# Read weighted graph from text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, weighted-graph

I have to create a weighted graph from a text file. Below is a example how the text file looks like. The first number is the id of the actual train station. The second number is a possible destination and after the comma is the time in seconds, it takes to travel. The the third number is another possible destination.

```
060060101832 060063101842,78 060054104822,90
060054104822 060060101832,90 060057104812,90 060058101502,90 060054105611,66
060057104812 060054104822,90 060057102802,72
```

I want to store the routes in an ArrayList. Each route object should look like this:

```
Start: 060060101832 
Destination: 060063101842
Time: 78
```

The problem is, I have to store multiple routes for the same starting location. How do I read the lines properly in, using a scanner? My approach was this:

```
while (routes.hasNext()) {
        routes.useDelimiter(",| |\\n");
        String start = routes.next();
        String dest= routes.next();
        String time= routes.next();
        Edge edge = new Edge(start, dest, time);
        edges.add(edge);
    }
```

Since I cannot go back in the text file, I can't imagine how a right solution should look like.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not a complete code** nor it was tested. It may or may not work but it will guide you anyways.

```
// Java 8
Node n;
Edge e;
String[] splittedLine;
String[] splittedEdge;
HashMap<String, Node> stationNumberToNode = new HashMap<>();
// if the file is not too large, you can read the file at once
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("path/to/file.txt").getPath());
for(String line : lines){
  splittedLine = line.split(" ");
  if((n = stationNumberToNode.get(splittedLine[0]) == null){
    n = new Node(splittedLine[0]); // assuming your Node has a constructor that takes the station id
    stationNumberToNode.put(stationNumberToNode[0], n);
  }
  for(int i = 1; i < splittedLine.lenght; ++i){
    splittedEdge = splittedLine[i].split(",");
    e = new Edge(splittedEdge[0], splittedEdge[1]); // assuming your Edgehas a constructor that takes the destination station and the cost
    n.addEdge(e);
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

```
Node n;
Edge e;
String[] splittedLine;
String[] splittedEdge;
HashMap<String, Node> stationNumberToNode = new HashMap<>();
```

Ideally you should always declare variables **outside** loops, so you avoid allocating a new memory on every iteration. Thus, we declare our 5 variables before entering the loop. The `HashMap` is used here to cover the case that your input is not always grouped and you avoid having to perform a list search everytime.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("path/to/file.txt").getPath());
```

Read all the lines on the file at once. Alternatively, as requested on the question, you can read the file using `Scanner` like on [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44630107/1806193). You have to change the way you iterate over the lines, though.

```
splittedLine = line.split(" ");
```

Splits the line on the " ", since your input file is well formated.

```
if((n = stationNumberToNode.get(splittedLine[0]) == null){
  n = new Node(splittedLine[0]); // assuming your Node has a constructor that takes the station id
  stationNumberToNode.put(stationNumberToNode[0], n);
}
```

Checks if the current node is already on the `HashMap`. If yes, it will be stored in the variable `n`. Else, it will create a `Node` with the current id and add it to our `HashMap`.

```
for(int i = 1; i < splittedLine.lenght; ++i){
  splittedEdge = splittedLine[i].split(",");
  e = new Edge(splittedEdge[0], splittedEdge[1]); // assuming your Edgehas a constructor that takes the destination station and the cost
  n.addEdge(e);
}
```

Since everything in the input file is the destination station and its cost (id,cost), we iterate on the `splittedLine` from index 1 onwards.
For every edge data, we split based on "," (from your input file), whereas `splittedEdge[0]` will be the destination id and `splittedEdge[1]` will be the cost to that destination. We create an `Edge` with that information and add that `Edge` to the `Node` object.