# How to read a file with file.separator in Java

Tags: java, file

```
String path = "C:" + File.separator + "testFolder" + File.separator + "one.txt";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(path);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());//prints C:\testFolder\one.txt once
}
```

**Edit:** My file one.txt contains 3 lines of text I would like java to loop through all the lines and print me those three lines. But I only get  "C:\testFolder\one.txt" printed on the console once only
with this code.

This seems to happen only when i am using file.separator for the file path, if I use `C:\\testFolder\\one.txt` or `C:/testFolder/one.txt` for file path it loops through the file and reads the file with all three lines. What can be done to read the whole file with the `File.separator`?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/13185765

Comment: What output do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a .txt file using Scanner class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185727/reading-a-txt-file-using-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: Refer to documentation for [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)). You are calling wrong constructor. Also refer to [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

Comment: `= new Scanner (Paths.get("C:", "testFolder", "one.txt"))` is what you need

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Scanner(String source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)) constructor, but you probably want to use Scanner(File source) constructor. Try:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path));
```

Comment: Your answer is essentially the same as my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609577/how-to-read-a-file-with-file-separator-in-java#comment131696291_74609577). I would also like to think that the OP could ascertain how to fix his code by looking at both the documentation and the other SO question that I linked to in that comment.

Comment: String path = "C:" + File.separator + "testFolder" + File.separator + "one.txt";

        System.out.println(path);
        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine()); //prints nothing in the console
        }
this doesn't seem to work as it prints nothing int he console, previously it printed the path.