java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7
I am getting below error when building using maven in intelliJ. Been trying to resolve in many way. Tried deleting .m2 repository, changing configurations in intelliJ including configuration in settings.xml in /.m2/settings.xml. Let me know if anyone has solution for this.
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/23.5.0.24.07/ojdbc8-23.5.0.24.07.pom
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download(MavenPomDownloader.java:487)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies(ResolvedPom.java:579)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies(ResolvedPom.java:502)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies(MavenResolutionResult.java:179)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs(MavenParser.java:124)
        at org.springframework.sbm.build.impl.RewriteMavenParser.parseInputs(RewriteMavenParser.java:92)
        at org.springframework.sbm.project.parser.MavenProjectParser.parse(MavenProjectParser.java:94)
        at org.springframework.sbm.project.parser.ProjectContextInitializer.initProjectContext(ProjectContextInitializer.java:52)
        at org.springframework.sbm.engine.commands.ScanCommand.execute(ScanCommand.java:70)
        at org.springframework.sbm.SpringBootMigratorRunner.run(SpringBootMigratorRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762)
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/23.5.0.24.07/ojdbc8-23.5.0.24.07.pom


Can you share your pom.xml file?

Unfortunately I cannot share my pom.xml file due to company policies. But I checked my pom.xml file thoroughly and it has been correct

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609577/how-to-read-a-file-with-file-separator-in-java#comment139652967_74609577.

Without the pom.xml file, it’s difficult to provide specific guidance, but it appears the issue may be related to how the file path is declared—likely within a configuration file, properties file, or the pom.xml itself. To find the relevant location, you can search for the file path using Ctrl + Shift + F.
Currently, the file path:
file://C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository/...

should be updated to:
file:///C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/...

In simple words: replace the backslashes '\' with forward slashes '/'. If you encounter another path related errors after fixing this, verify the path you are using is correct. Hopefully, this will resolve the issue.
